# Postgres Select all Sundays in 2019

Tags: postgresql

how would I go about selecting data from only Sundays in 2019 in Postgres?

I think Sundays are a 0 but I am unsure as to how to query it like that.

I am selecting from a preexisting table that contains timestamp strings like 2020-09-03 02:11:60, so basically I want to select all the timestamps that occurred in 2019 in my table usermetrics in the column timestamp.

Comment: This is going to need more information. Are you selecting from preexisting dates in table(s) and only want to those that fall on a Sunday in 2019? Or do you want  generate a list of Sunday dates in 2019.?

Comment: yes I am selecting from a preexisting table that contains timestamp strings like 2020-09-03 02:11:60, so basically I want to select all the timestamps that occurred in 2019 in my table usermetrics in the column timestamp

Answer (score 1):

You have two requests.
The first to find timestamps in 2019:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
    usermetrics 
WHERE 
     timestamp BETWEEN '01/01/2019'::date AND '01/01/2020'::date
```

The second to find those that occurred on Sundays:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    usermetrics 
WHERE 
     timestamp BETWEEN '01/01/2019'::date AND '01/01/2020'::date 
AND 
     extract(DOW FROM timestamp) = 0;
```

`01/01/2020::date` is used as `12/31/2019::date` would miss timestamps that occurred after midnight.